# How to compose a query, uaing LIKE in CdBCriteria?

Tags: activerecord, yii

I've read some posts, documentation. And still don't understand why this code doesn't work. Can someone help me to solve this stuff?

```
class SearchController extends Controller
{
    public function actionResults()
    {
        $search = $this->getPost('search', '');

        $criteria = new CDbCriteria();

        $criteria->condition = 'username like :username';

        $criteria->params = array(
            ':username' => '"%' . $search . '%"'
        );

        $results = User::model()
            ->findAll($criteria);

        $this->render('search', array(
            'search' => $search,
            'results' => $results,
        ));
    }
}
```

Yii profiler always show me this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `user` `t` WHERE username like :username
```

I don't understand why ":username" remains ":username" and isn't substitute with $search value.

---

I've solved with this solution:

```
class SearchController extends Controller
{
    public function actionResults()
    {
        $results = User::model()
            ->findAll(array(
                'condition' => 'username like :username',
                'params' => array(
                    ':username' => '%'. $this->getPost('search') .'%'
                )
            ));

        $this->render('search', array(
            'search' => $this->getPost('search'),
            'results' => $results,
        ));
    }
}
```

But still don't understand why profiler show me incomplete query instead of the renderized query.

Comment: Can be rewrited to `$results = User::model()->findAll('username LIKE :username',array(':username'=>'%'. $this->getPost('search') .'%'));` Quite shorter but doing same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use addSearchCondition function like this,
for ref http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addSearchCondition-detail

```
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->addSearchCondition('username',$search);
```

Comment: Returns "SELECT * FROM `user` `t` WHERE username LIKE :ycp0". What is ":ycp0"?

Comment: :ycp0 is auto generated bind param its value is $search.

Comment: I know that =). I dont know why the value is not binded!

Answer (score 0):

```
class SearchController extends Controller
{
    public function actionResults()
    {
        $results = User::model()
            ->findAll(array(
                'condition' => 'username like :username',
                'params' => array(
                    ':username' => '%'. $this->getPost('search') .'%'
                )
            ));

        $this->render('search', array(
            'search' => $this->getPost('search'),
            'results' => $results,
        ));
    }
}
```